# Showing current category - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

I need to show current category name on posts index.

Insted of "Jubotron" it should shows test (when test category is chosen)

[image: Insted of "Jubotron" it should shows test (when test category is chosen)]

My code

Controllers

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    cate = params[:cate]

    if !cate.nil?
      @blogs = Category.find(params[:cate]).blogs
    else
      @blogs = Blog.all
    end

  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.create(blog_params)

    if @blog.save
      redirect_to @blog
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    #finds the blog id
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

def update
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  if @blog.update(blog_params)
    redirect_to @blog
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

def destroy
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])

  @blog.destroy
  redirect_to :action => :index
end

  private
  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :content, category_ids: [])
  end
end
```

```
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:category)
    end
end
```

blogs/index.html.erb

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h1 style="text-align:center">Jumbotron</h1>
<%= @categories.each do |category|  %>
<%= category.category %>
<% end %>

      <div class="row">

        <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card mt-3">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h3><%= link_to blog.title, blog_path(blog.id) %></h3>
                <p><%= blog.content %></p>
                <%= link_to "Pokaż", blog_path(blog.id), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                <br></br>
                <div class="">
                  Kategoria:
                  <% blog.categories.each do |category| %>
                  <a><%= link_to category.category,blogs_path(:cate => category.id) %></a>
                  <% end %>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
            <% end %>

        </div>
      </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Kategorie:

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <ul class="list-group">
        <% @categories.each do |category| %>

  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <%= link_to category.category, blogs_path(:cate => category.id) %>

    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"><%= category.blogs.count %></span>
  </li>

  <% end %>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>


  </div>
</div>
```

and for example I can show category name in categories/show.htm.erb

but when I past it into Blogs index it gives me an error that category method is undefined.

````
  <strong>Category:</strong>
  <%= @category.category %>
</p> ```


Any ideas?
````

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is where you are placing your 'Jumbotron' code. Currently, you're hardcoding the word 'Jumbotron' like this:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center">Jumbotron</h1>
```

You should move this inside the code where you are iterating over the categories:

```
<% @categories.each do |category|  %>
  <h1 style="text-align:center"><%= category.category %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Keep in mind, if you have more than one category, this is going to give you multiple `<h1>` tags; one for each category.

Comment: oh thank you, how can i show just one exact category?

Comment: You’ll either have to find the category and store it in instance variable in your controller then use that instance variable in your view or you can use `.first` or `.last` methods to get the first or last category.

Answer (score 0):

On the index page you are looping through the categories `<% @categories.each do |category| %>` thus you should use `category.category` and not `@category.category` inside the block